# Will Ubuntu Media Server meet my needs?

Tags: server, media

Can somebody help me determine what the best way to accomplish the following requirements for my media server?

1. Movie storage / playback
2. Music storage / playback
3. Netflix, Hulu, etc
4. Sports streaming from ESPN3.com
5. Sports streaming from other (shady) web streaming services

The real question is how best to do the web streaming. I want to make it so that I can just plop on the couch and fire up the TV without needing to get my laptop and plug in the HDMI.

Comment: How about you test it and check it out, then decide if it meets your needs?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few devices out there that connect via Bluetooth from your computer to the TV. You can use one of these to make your life easier. OR, get an Xbox ONE :)

Check out [Chrome Cast](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=chromecast&gclid=CJix7LmbmrsCFbB9Ogod9RMAPA)  Cheap and effective.

Comment: may I ask who down voted me and why? I wouldn't mind seeing their suggestion to help this problem.